# How to call viewModel method which updates binding data from worker thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, data-binding

I have a worker thread which calculates data for DataGrid after every change user have made. In some cases user make changes too fast so on GUI thread i call

```
Thread.Abort();
```

in the meantime on the worker thread i use such a construction

```
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            _calculateEvent.WaitOne();

            ...

            Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                _viewModel.UpdateInterfaceFromAssigningInfo(assigningInfo);
            });
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
     }
```

Don't know if it will work at all, but for now my main problem is i can't call code on the GUI thread to update interface. At `Invoke` row i have exception: `InvalidOperationException` with message

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

Comment: Instead of having a blocked thread running in the background all the time, would it be viable in your case to start an `async` task each time you want to start the calculations? Using CancelationTokens you can still cancel those if necessary and updating the GUI would be straightforward since you just `await` the result of your calculations.

Comment: @HW but still i would have the same problem with calling to GUI thread.

Comment: you wouldn't since you await the async task WITHIN your GUI thread - thus the GUI thread is updating itself as soon as the async method completes and delivers a result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches i have found info that accurately fills my needs, because in my case i need to update UI only after all calculation in Task have been done.

**Option 1.**
For the case of WPF application we can benefit from *synchronization context task scheduler* which runs task right on GUI thread. So, one can employ such scenario to update GUI after task has finished:

```
        Task t = Task.Run(() => foo());

        t.ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            // Update observable properties 
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Continuation task will be executed on GUI thread and so will be able to update GUI.

**Option 2**

```
private async void DownloadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Since we asynchronously wait, the UI thread is not blocked by our code.
  await foo();

  // Since we resume on the UI context, we can directly access UI elements.
  UpdateObservableProperties();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually use slightly different way:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action( ()=>

            {
                _viewModel.UpdateInterfaceFromAssigningInfo(assigningInfo);
            }));
```

Try, may be it's a reason.